# Calling a typed generic deep sort method

Tags: typescript, generics

```
public sortDeepVersions<T, K extends keyof T>(
    key: K,
    subKey: keyof T[K],
    collection: Array<T>
  ) {
    return this.sortOnDeepProperty(key, subKey, collection, versionComparator);
  }
```

...

```
testMockedPacks = sorter.sortDeepVersions(
        'latestVersion',
        'version',
        testMockedPacks
);
```

In the above case testMockedPacks is an array of objects that have the property latestVersion.version.

Attempting the above gives an error on 'version', that "argument of type string is not assignable to type never". How should I correctly call sortDeepVersions?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/vW4e7w) so that others can easily demonstrate your issue for themselves, and where no extraneous issues are present.  If I go through the trouble of trying to do this myself, [I cannot reproduce your issue](https://tsplay.dev/KWznQW), so hopefully you can shed some light on it.

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks for the advice, I'll look into it.

Comment: It was because latestVersion type ... | null so it couldn't rely on it not being null.

Comment: So, should we close this question?